# Can we search all the public post referring a particular keyword using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get all facebook posts with the sdk by searching with one word

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on https://developers.facebook.com/docs ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this, for normal 3rd-party apps.

What you can search for via Graph API, is quite limited - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#search
(This used to include other stuff before, searching for users, etc., but most of that has since been removed.)

---

There is the Public Feed API - but that is not available to normal 3rd-party apps, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/:

> Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot apply to use the API at this time.